# Hello world program not compiling

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

Help, I was trying to make a hello world program, and i'm still a newbie at java. My program is called HelloWorld.java. This is my program

```
class hello world{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World! Are you proud?")
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you're missing a semicolon (`;`) after the `System.out.println("Hello World! Are you proud?")`

Comment: "My program is called HelloWorld.java" then your public class in that file should also be called `HelloWorld` not `hello world`. Names can't contain spaces and Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name cannot have spaces. Also:

Missing semicolon

```
System.out.println("Hello World! Are you proud?")
```

Should become

```
System.out.println("Hello World! Are you proud?");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class name cannot contain spaces

```
 class hello world
```

it should be declared

```
 class HelloWorld
```

and for the naming convention your class should start with capital letters
and also your print  statement should be like this

```
  System.out.println("Hello World! Are you proud?");
```